# setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener не работает | BottomNavigationView | Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-navigation-view, setonclicklistener

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.book_bottom_view)
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_book_home -> {
                log("nav_book_home")
            }
            R.id.nav_book_chapters -> {
                log("nav_book_chapters")
            }
            R.id.nav_book_comments -> {
                log("nav_book_comments")
            }
        }
        return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
    }

    val tool = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.book_toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(tool)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_book_fragment)

    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_book_home, R.id.nav_book_chapters, R.id.nav_book_comments
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    renderFragment()
}
```

Почему setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener не работает? Должно выводить в консоль сообщение, но она пуста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я совершил глупую ошибку. Я добавлял обработчик на фрагмент до того, как объявлял сам фрагмент.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.book_bottom_view)

    val tool = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.book_toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(tool)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_book_fragment)

    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_book_home, R.id.nav_book_chapters, R.id.nav_book_comments
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_book_home -> {
                log("nav_book_home")
            }
            R.id.nav_book_chapters -> {
                log("nav_book_chapters")
            }
            R.id.nav_book_comments -> {
                log("nav_book_comments")
            }
        }
        return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
    }

    renderFragment()
}
```

Перенес обработчик в конец функции и все заработало.